# Can I only write assembly code for my computer architecture/instruction set?

Tags: assembly, cross-compiling

I was just wondering if I could only write assembly code that is specific to my processor? Would I have to download a VM of the instruction set that I am targeting to be able to write assembly code for that?

Comment: No, cross-assemblers are a thing, e.g. `clang -target arm -c foo.s` will assemble for ARM, as will `arm-none-eabi-as`.  So are simulators with a built-in IDE like MARS or RARS, or Easy68k, which also conveniently let you test and debug such asm without also needing QEMU + gdb-multiarch.  (Being able to assemble is usually not sufficient to write programs; you do need to be able to run and debug unless the program is very small, you know what you're doing, and you don't mind the possibility of silly mistakes.)

Comment: Writing assembly just requires a text editor in some form.  Assembling, running, debugging can be done using simulators and such. Some simulators are online websites, such as for [LC-3](https://wchargin.com/lc3web/), [MARIE](https://marie.js.org), others.